# I've to test old HIPPI network cards in Linux. How can I do this?

Tags: linux, networking

LSPCI does show the cards have been recognised by the system but I really don't know what to do to check the cards functionality. How can I setup a test network or something else to verify the cards aren't broken?

It would be really helpfull if someone has an idea because we have a customer who is still interessted to buy these cards.

I'm working with a Fedora 17 x86 with a 3.4.9-1 Kernel on a HP xw4100 workstation but other machines are available too.

Comment: More detail is needed! OS distribution, kernel, hardware type, etc.

Comment: This is all I know. These are HIPPI network cards and I've to check if they are broken or still useable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just:

1. connect them to another network card in the same machine with some network cable,
2. then `ifconfig up` them both while making sure they are in the same network (use a different IP  that belongs to the same network as specified by the netmask, e.g. 192.168.0.1/24 and 192.168.0.2/24).
3. then check `route -n` and make sure traffic for that network is routed correctly.
4. then you can `ping -I` from one interface to another and check if the card is working.

To do some stress test, you could try `ping -f`.

Comment: I tried but ifconfig -a doesn't know about the cards

Comment: @KaaiKivi do you have the kernel modules for the card? IOW, what is the output of `zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_HIPPI`?

Comment: "No such file or directory"

Comment: @KaaiKivi oh right, you probably don't have the runtime config support in your kernel. Can you `modprobe hippi`? If not, it is either compiled in into your kernel, or not present at all. Maybe try compiling a kernel with `CONFIG_HIPPI` enabled. See http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/HIPPI.html for details.

Comment: It seems the HIPPI support is missing. I'll try to compile a kernel later. Thanks a lot!